# How show any particular message or excute javascript error when excpetion occured on ajax method?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi I have a commandButton which calls a java method ajax. I want to show error message or do any specific javascrpt method call when error occured in managed bean(i.e. NullPointerException)

I have seen to the user guide of primefaces where commandButton has onerror attribute. I am not sure when it get called.

My code is like this.

```
<p:commandButton action="#{myBean.myMethod}" onsuccess="alert('success');" onerror="myJavaScriptMethod();"/>

<script>
   function myJavaScriptMethod(){
        alert('Exception occured in managed bean');
   }
</script>
```

My Java Method

```
public void myMethod(){
      throw new Exception("Failed to do operation");
}
```

I want to call "myJavaScriptMethod" in client side.

Answer (score 1):

Better solution instead of `onerror` is to call script from your method `myMethod()`. That should look like

```
public void myMethod(){
      try {
          // your code goes here
      } catch(Exception e) {
          RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("your script");
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your ans. I would like to call it from client side so that I can keep my java code separate from xhtml code.

Comment: jsf.ajax.addOnError(handleError);
var handleError = function handleError(data) {
}

Comment: I did not understand how to use it.

Comment: I tried to use your code like- RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("alert('My method excuted')") . It didnt work for me :(

Comment: Are you sure that execution reaches catch block?

Comment: ya I am sure because I am throwing exception intensionally

Comment: And can you tell what scope of bean do you use?